# Postgres query compare if two dates are equal with margin

Tags: postgresql, select, timestamp, where-clause

I have the following query in Postgres:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE registration = last_login;
```

Both registration and last_login are timestamps. The problem I have is that those two values are written with some tiny difference, but they are not exact. Is there any way I can compare those two dates with a margin of, say, 1 second?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a_horse_with_no_name actualy has answered your question but just for case when there's no guarantee one date is after another you could try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE @extract(epoch from registration - last_login) <= 1;
```

extract(epoch from some_interval) returns timestamp difference in seconds as a number, and @some_value returns absolute value of a number, just like abs(some_value)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `last_login` is always *after*  `registration`, you can check the difference between the two timestamps

```
select *
from users
where last_login - registration <= interval '1' second
```